# How to detect the idleness of bot in framework v4 with C#?

Tags: c#, timestamp, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have bot made in framework V4 using c#. Is very simple bot fetching answer from qna maker. In my case I want to find out the idleness of bot once their no more interaction between the user and bot, suppose after 5 minutes so that I can take user feedback.

**Approach Followed by me:-**

I followed this link [how to detect bot Idleness on Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894802/how-to-detect-bot-idleness-on-bot-framework), But the solution given here is in V3 that doesn't solve my problem.

Does anyone have idea about this kind of issue? Please help me out.