# how to detect the idleness of bot in framework v4 using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a bot made in framework v4 using *c#*. I want to send user a feedback card in  case if bot goes idle, but i  am not able to achieve it. I tried my ways to do it but i failed. I followed this link , but it for v3 and not working in my case, [how to detect bot Idleness on Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894802/how-to-detect-bot-idleness-on-bot-framework) . Is any one really knows how to achieve it.

Can any one tell the steps or logic , how to achieve it.

Comment: If you are using directline webchat, you should be able to use this method to "time out" the conversation and display whatever activity you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939184/set-timer-using-microsoft-bot-framework/54952783#comment106298770_54952783

Comment: @Billoverton can tell me how to do it for c#? using bot frameowrk v4

Comment: Webchat code would be the same. I don't program in C# but it should be all the same steps. Check for event (note in the comments you should use onEvent, not onTurn), if the activity has a name and it is "inactive", send the message and name it "inactive". The last piece prevents the timer from being restarted when you send the proactive message.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2385 and https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5237 as well with addition to the above. As specified above, you can make use of proactive messages or make use of azure queue.